# Why is my Pytest function not catching on coverage?

Tags: python, pytest

I am learning pytest, and when I look at my coverage HTML file, it says one of my functions is not covered.

Here is my function:

```py
def add(a, b): 
    """Add two numbers.""" 
    if not isinstance(a, int): 
        raise ValueError('a is not an integer') 
        return None 
    if not isinstance(b, int): 
        raise ValueError('b is not an integer') 
        return None 
    return a + b
```

and here is my test function (my function is in the file `specs.py`):

```py
def test_add(): 
    assert specs.add(1, 3) == 4, "failed on positive integers" 
    assert specs.add(-5, -7) == -12, "failed on negative integers" 
    assert specs.add(-6, 14) == 8, "failed on a mix of positive and negative integers" 
    assert specs.add('3', 4) == None, "a is not an integer" 
    assert specs.add(3, '4') == None, "b is not an integer"
```

Pytest says that everything passes, but when I look at my test_specs file, it says it is not covered. I have written many other functions on the same file that are covered, so I am not sure why this function is not covered.

Comment: I'm wondering how the last two tests could pass.

Answer (score 0):

The `return None` statement after you raise the `ValueError` are unreachable. They will never be covered. To check the raised `Exception`, you should use `pytest.raises`([doc](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/assert.html#assertions-about-expected-exceptions)).

```py
def add(a, b):
    """Add two numbers."""
    if not isinstance(a, int):
        raise ValueError('a is not an integer')
        # return None
    if not isinstance(b, int):
        raise ValueError('b is not an integer')
        # return None
    return a + b


def test_add():
    assert add(1, 3) == 4, "failed on positive integers"
    assert add(-5, -7) == -12, "failed on negative integers"
    assert add(-6, 14) == 8, "failed on a mix of positive and negative integers"
    with pytest.raises(ValueError) as exc_info:
        add('3', 4)
    # print(exc_info)
    assert exc_info.type == ValueError
    assert str(exc_info.value) == "a is not an integer"
    with pytest.raises(ValueError) as exc_info:
        add(3, '4')
    
    # print(exc_info)
    assert exc_info.type == ValueError
    assert str(exc_info.value) == "b is not an integer"
```